# Codeigniter - 4.2 - 404 File not found on post submit

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I just made a new installation of Codeigniter 4.2. It worked fine. Then, I copied the controllers, models and views from my existing project in Codeigniter 4.1.9.

The application loads fine. When the application makes post submit, it always shows 404 - File not found.

I have set the routes->setAutoRoute(true); in Routes.php and Set `$autoRoutesImproved` to true in `app/Config/Feature.php.

Still getting the same error.

Comment: please provide some code example of that Post submit. Did it work on your localhost? is php version the same, any error messages if you set env to development?

Comment: It is in Wampserver. It is not working. PHP version is 7.4. No other error messages. env is set to development. It works well in 4.1.9.

Comment: without seeing an error/error log, this will be quite impossible to answer

Comment: Do you have a htaccess handling the rewriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since v4.2.0, Auto-Routing has been disabled by default. Because it is easy to create vulnerable apps where controller filters or CSRF protection are bypassed.

But if you want to run v4.1.9 apps, you need to set `$routes->setAutoRoute(true)` in Routes.php and set `$autoRoutesImproved` to `false` in `app/Config/Feature.php`.